# woocommerce changer time stamp $orderdate = $order->order_date;

Tags: php, woocommerce, export

I am exporting order data from woocommerce. For the order date, I am using:

```
// Get order
$order = wc_get_order($id);

// Get order date
$orderdate = $order->order_date;
```

Now the order date appears in de xml file as "2020-10-15 06:53:36". I would only like to display the date and not the time. I have tried adding format('Y-m-d'):

```
// Get order date
$orderdate = $order->format('Y-m-d')->order_date;
```

Doesnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `get_date_created()`

```
$order->get_date_created()->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($orderdate));`